# iot core error when use ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync execute process

Tags: c#, uwp, launcher

I want to run another program from my program
my code is

```
    var options = new ProcessLauncherOptions();
            var standardOutput = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var standardError = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            options.StandardOutput = standardOutput;
            options.StandardError = standardError;
             await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync(@"C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\930e206e-dd28-4760-84b2-f3a1f74801feVS.Debug_ARM.Mostafa.Bagheri\Jamsaz.InjectionWeights.exe", "", options);
```

when i run in vs 2017 get following error

> This application can only run in the context of an app container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109B)
>   [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJISO.jpg)

Comment: I add Execute Permission to Registry on file
reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher" /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\930e206e-dd28-4760-84b2-f3a1f74801feVS.Debug_ARM.Mostafa.Bagheri\Jamsaz.InjectionWeights.exe"\0

Comment: I Run on Debug mode visual studio

Comment: Is your program a UWP application?

Comment: Hi
Yes is Uwp App and run on Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

You may need including the executable application with the AppX package. For detailed steps, you can reference this tutorial:

[External process launcher](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/externalprocesslauncher).